# Python command line Import Error

Tags: python

I'm facing a strange problem in Python imports. I've written a simple Python module, called `test.py`. It contains:

```
import wx
```

When I run this code in IDLE, it runs successfully. But when I run the same module through command-line, it gives me an `ImportError: no module named wx`.
It is not an error related to wx library for two reasons. One, because it runs on IDLE. And two, I'm unable to run any module with an import statement in command-line.

PS: I've set all the environment variables. (C:\Python27\; C:\Python27\Scripts).

What may be the problem?

Comment: use print sys.path in your command-line to verify if your test path is included

Comment: `'when I type the following'`, the following?

Comment: If you type `python` what do you get? Type `import sys` and `sys.path` and see whether `wx` is in the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the command line under your script folder.

---

For instance,

Your test.py was under the folder: `~/scripts/test.py`,

then you should first change to this folder: `cd ~/scripts`

and run the python command-line: `python` or `python test.py`.

---

The reason is that:

You IDE has already changed to your file folder, since you can run it.

But the command-line was not.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the problem as described. How would they get `ImportError: no module named wx`?