# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, python-import

I'm trying to run my python script that I developed/tested through IDE and it's working fine over there.

But when I try to run the same script on Command Prompt (`Windows 10`) which has to import any module. Note that `python` script and the `.bat` file is in the same directory.

I think this is happening environment setup so I did some search and found these posts below;

[import error: 'No module named' *does* exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417941/import-error-no-module-named-does-exist/40883739#40883739)

[No module error when running python script from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050336/no-module-error-when-running-python-script-from-command-prompt)

[Python command line Import Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957518/python-command-line-import-error)

[Unable to imoprt modules on python script while running on cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106665/unable-to-imoprt-modules-on-python-script-while-running-on-cmd)

[Package doesn't work if run from cmd or from the .py file.... PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53672940/package-doesnt-work-if-run-from-cmd-or-from-the-py-file-python)

https://www.programmersought.com/article/7436148385/

Here is the error snapshot

[image]

Steps followed

1. Python version 3.8.3
2. Environment variables are set under system environment variables
   [image]
3. in the 'code.py' also added

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.append('D:\program_files\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages')
   ```
4. `Seaborn` and `Scipy` updated the latest versions
5. CMD FILE look like this

[image]

I followed older solutions like set up environment variables for python libraries and python path so for not even close to get rid of this error.

Any idea to help what I'm missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that your IDE is pointing to any specific virtual or conda environment?

Comment: @BernardL This is what I got when I input print(sys.path)  in `CMD` `'D:\\program_files\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'D:\\program_files\\anaconda3\\python38.zip', 'D:\\program_files\\anaconda3\\DLLs', 'D:\\program_files\\anaconda3\\lib', 'D:\\program_files\\anaconda3', 'D:\\program_files\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'D:\\program_files\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'D:\\program_files\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'D:\\program_files\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions'`

Comment: Can you run `print(sys.prefix)` for both the IDE and default command line?

Comment: @BernardL for CMD it is : D:\program_files\anaconda3
for IDE: D:\program_files\anaconda3